# {change the color of DataGrid Cell after updating rows}

Tags: vb.net

basically what i want is when change the status and update it will change the color of that updated cell
here is my code:

```
Private Sub Btnupdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click
    Try
        Dim datePublish As String = Format(dtpDatePublish.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")

        If txtAccessionNo.Text = "" Or txtAuthor.Text = "" Or txtTitle.Text = "" Or TxtBoxISBN.Text = "" Or txtPublisher.Text = "" Or CBSection.Text = "" Or TxtBoxSubject.Text = "" Or TxtBoxYearPub.Text = "" Or TxtBoxShelf.Text = "" Or TxtBoxCallNumber.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("All fields are required to be filled up.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            sql = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `AccessionNo` = '" & txtAccessionNo.Text & "'"
            reloadtxt(sql)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                panelstatus.Visible = True
                sqledit = "UPDATE `books` SET `Isbn`='" & TxtBoxISBN.Text & "',
                `BookSection` = '" & CBSection.SelectedItem & "', `Subject` = '" & TxtBoxSubject.Text & "', `Title` = '" & txtTitle.Text & "',
                     `Author` = '" & txtAuthor.Text & "', `JointAuthor` = '" & txtjointauthor.Text & "', `Publisher` = '" & txtPublisher.Text & "', 
                    `YearPublish` = '" & TxtBoxYearPub.Text & "', `Edition` = '" & TxtBoxEdition.Text & "', `Volume` = '" & TxtBoxVolume.Text & "', 
                   `Aquistion` = '" & CBAquisition.SelectedItem & "', `DateAquired` = '" & datePublish & "', `SponsorPrice` = '" & TxtBoxPrice.Text & "',
                   `Shelf` = '" & TxtBoxShelf.Text & "', `CallNumber` = '" & TxtBoxCallNumber.Text & "', `Remarks` = '" & TxtBoxRemarks.Text & "', `Status` = '" & CBstatus.SelectedItem & "' WHERE `AccessionNo` = '" & txtAccessionNo.Text & "'"

                save_or_update(sql, sqladd, sqledit, "Books has been updated in the database.", "New books has been saved in the database.")

                Call InventoryAdd_Load(sender, e)
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

here is my cell formatting code

```
Private Sub DtgList1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dtgList1.CellFormatting
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtgList1.Rows
        If row.Cells(17).Value = "Available" Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Handle the `CellFormatting` event of the grid. That event is raised at various times, including when a value changes. You can set the colour of the cell based on the value in the event handler. Plenty of examples about.

Comment: Here is my code in cell Formatting

Comment: Private Sub DtgList1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dtgList1.CellFormatting
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtgList1.Rows
            If row.Cells(17).Value = "Available" Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

Comment: suddenly i got this error  'Conversion from string "Available" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

Comment: That is very, very wrong. If someone points you in a particular direction, the idea is that you do some actual research on what they suggest. The point of the `CellFormatting` event is that it is raised when a specific cell is being formatted so you can handle that specific cell and ONLY that specific cell. No loops. No rows. Just that cell. The `e` parameter tells you what cell it is and then you format that cell and ONLY that cell. If the whole grid needs formatting then the event will be raised once for each cell.

Comment: Also, you said in your title and question that you wanted to change the colour of cells and yet the code you posted suggests that you want to change the colour of rows. If you clearly express your problem then it's rather hard to provide a relevant solution.

Comment: Finally, why would you set a property to `White` and then immediately set it to `Red`? It can't be both colours at the same time. It looks like you have taken code from an answer, butchered it a little and then pasted it into a different event. You might need to put a bit more thought into it than that. There are appropriate places and inappropriate places to put code depending on what that code does. You can't just pick up code from one event handler and put it in another and expect the same result.

Comment: thank you all! i already solved it ..

Answer (score 0):

When adding row colours to DataGridViews, I normally handle the Paint event.  The error 'Conversion from string "Available" to type 'Double' is not valid suggests that row.Cells(17).Value is a Double, not a string.  Are you sure that's the correct column?

From your code, I'm guessing your column is called 'Status'.  If not, rename below as needed, or continue to use column number but ensure it's the correct column.  As you are using Select * to populate your table, I'd suggest using a Column Name is more reliable as column order may change or new columns added to the database in future.

```
Private Sub dtgList1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles dtgList1.Paint
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dtgList1.Rows
        If rw.Cells("Status").Value = "Available" Then
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```